# Delete all images from cells except last one in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have images in cells which are same so I want to delete all except last one (keep only one).

I 've below code, but it does work only for one cell. I see that there is something wrong in delete code.

```
Sub CellImageCheck()  '' Delete multiple images in cells
    Dim checkRange As Range
    Dim x As Shape
    Dim flag As Boolean
    'On Error Resume Next

Dim WorkRng As Range
Set WorkRng = Range("E1:E372")

        For Each x In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            m = Range(x.TopLeftCell.Address).Row
            Cells(m, 7).Value = Cells(m, 7).Value + 1 '' write image count from cell in respetice row in E column
        Next
        
        ''' Delete all images in cell except last
        For Each x In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        m = Range(x.TopLeftCell.Address).Row
        
            For Each Rng In WorkRng
                If Cells(m, 7).Value > 1 Then
                    Cells(m, 7).Value = Cells(m, 7).Value - 1
                    x.Delete
                End If
            Next
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the "last" shape you want a specific one?  What determines which one should remain?  Do you mean you have multiple images with the same `TopLeftCell` and you want to delete all but one in each set?

Comment: Should this "last one" be a shape on the lower row and maximum column? Should it be the las created one shape? Please, try defining this sintagma/concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to track which cells have already been associated with a shape, then delete any "extra" shapes also associated with the same cell.

```vb
Sub CellImageCheck()  
    
    Dim i As Long, addr, dict As Object
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    For i = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes(i)
            addr = .TopLeftCell.Address(0, 0)
            If Not dict.exists(addr) Then
                dict.Add addr, True  'first shape over this cell
            Else
                .Delete              'already have a shape for this cell
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect and precise! Thanks!